# Automatically display any metadata credits for non-service layers in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, layers, metadata, dynamic-text

By default, ArcGIS Pro displays credits for service layers in the bottom-right of the map frame.  This can also be added to a layout as dynamic text (in which case the default bottom-right version of the credits text disappears - allowing the user to manage the location appearance themselves).

Is there any way to get the credits (eg, stored in the image or mosaic metadata) for non-service layers to appear dynamically on the map as layers are added/removed e.g. using the "dynamic text" feature?

I have a few local imagery layers that we often use as basemaps, and I need to make sure they are credited correctly.  Rather than hard-coding all of the credits for all of these layers on the layout, I'd like the layout to automatically display credits for only the layer(s) that is actually on the map.  I would assume that the "Credits" field in the metadata would be the right place the enter the data, but I can't find any way for ArcGIS Pro to use this in "dynamic text" or otherwise.

Comment: I wish... This would be a good [ArcGIS Ideas](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-ideas/idb-p/arcgis-pro-ideas) addition. This is the [current list of available dynamic text tags](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/layouts/add-and-modify-dynamic-text.htm).  What you could do is hardcode into credits map frame or layout metadata, then add that as dynamic text.